# Create MultiSelectedListPreference using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, preferenceactivity, android-multiselectlistpreference

I'm trying to create a `PreferenceActicity`.
I need that on of my preferences will be of type `MultiSelectedListPreference`.

I found this code on the internet:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:dialogTitle="@string/mode_repeat"
    android:key="mode_repeat"
    android:summary=""        
    android:title="@string/mode_repeat"
    android:entries="@array/weekdays"
    android:entryValues="@array/weekdays_values"
    android:defaultValue="@array/empty_array"
    />
```

The problem is I'm getting the entries and entryValues in runtime.
I'm building the `ArrayList` while my app is running, the question is how can I set my `ArrayList` as the entries and as the `entryValues`?

Do I need to create an empty xml file, which I will re-write during the building of my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to change the xml in runtime. The solution for your problem is to use the methods `setEntries()`and `setEntryValues()`from the [`MultiSelectListPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.html) class.

Here's a basic code snippet:

```
MultiSelectListPreference repeatModePreference = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference(Constants. mode_repeat);
repeatModePreference.setEntries(yourEntries); // This is human-readable strings
repeatModePreference.setEntryValues(yourEntryvalues) // The value corresponding to the human-readable string
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It's working, just needed to cast from ArrayList<String> to CharSequence[] but that was easy, thanks again!